# If date is between two dates, find value using shared reference

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and having a hard time with something. I have a data frame containing, among other things, dates and the name of an advertising placement.

I have another table containing start date, end date, the name of the ad placement, and a rate.

I basically need to reference the rate key and apply a vlookup (left_join) to my data frame based on the date and placement name, considering the different rates that might occur for diff date ranges in my reference table.

So far I've been using dplyr pretty extensively to move things around, but this is the hardest thing I've come across so far. Initial thought is that I might need to make every possible date range it's own table and apply a left_join to the df, but I'm not sure.

Example:

**Reference table**

```
placement             start        end          rate 
NewYorkTimes_iPhone   2018-06-01   2018-06-25   5 
NewYorkTimes_iPhone   2018-06-26   2018-06-30   7
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
placement           date        rate 
NewYorkTimes_iPhone 2018-06-15  5
```

Basically in the dataframe the rate column would be missing. I need it to search the reference table for the shared placement and see if the date is between the range in the key

Any help is appreciated! This is my first r project and I've learned everything online through DataCamp.

Thank you!!

Tyler

Comment: Can you provide some example data, as well as an example of the expected output?

Comment: @jdobres edited to provide sample data

Comment: @lmo previously did that because I assumed it would be needed down the road. thank you

Comment: @Tyler That is good. Thanks for updating your question to provide this important information.

Comment: `dat$rate[dat1$date>=dat$start&dat1$date<=dat$end]` or you can do `dat$rate[data,table::between(dat1$date,dat$start,dat$end)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
> ref_tbl <- 
+     tibble(
+         placement = c("NewYorkTimes_iPhone","NewYorkTimes_iPhone"), 
+         start = c("2018-06-01","2018-06-26"),
+         end = c("2018-06-25","2018-06-30"),
+         rate = c(5,7)
+     ) %>% 
+     mutate_at(vars(start, end),as.Date)
> des_tbl <- 
+     tibble(
+         placement = "NewYorkTimes_iPhone",
+         date = "2018-06-15",
+         rate = 5
+     ) %>% 
+     mutate(date = as.Date(date))
> ref_tbl
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  placement           start      end         rate
  <chr>               <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 NewYorkTimes_iPhone 2018-06-01 2018-06-25     5
2 NewYorkTimes_iPhone 2018-06-26 2018-06-30     7
> des_tbl
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  placement           date        rate
  <chr>               <date>     <dbl>
1 NewYorkTimes_iPhone 2018-06-15     5
> 
> ref_tbl %>% 
+     left_join(des_tbl, by = c("placement","rate")) %>% 
+     mutate(
+         ifelse(date %within% interval(start,end),1,0)
+     )
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  placement           start      end         rate date       `ifelse(date %wit~
  <chr>               <date>     <date>     <dbl> <date>                  <dbl>
1 NewYorkTimes_iPhone 2018-06-01 2018-06-25     5 2018-06-15                  1
2 NewYorkTimes_iPhone 2018-06-26 2018-06-30     7 NA                         NA
>
```

Here is some comments.

For the left joined table, we need get the results where `date` is between `start` and `end`.
Here the function `%within%` and `interval` from `lubridate` package is a solution.